# vstest.console.exe --testcasefilter:"FullyQualifiedName=Namespace.classname is not working

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, specflow, vstest.console.exe, specrun

I'm a newbie in vstest and I'm trying to run the specflow feature file from command line. I've used the below command but's it's not working for me.

Below is the namespace and class name:

```
namespace PE.Feature.Preconditions.DeleteData
{
public partial class Preconditions_DeleteDataFeature
}
```

I've tried the below commands:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow>vstest.console.exe "D:\05NovRepo\PE\bin\Debug\PE.dll" --testcasefilter:"FullyQualifiedName=PE.Feature.Preconditions.DeleteData" /TestAdapterPath:"D:\05NovRepo\packages\SpecRun.Runner.3.0.344\tools\net45\"
```

Another One:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow>vstest.console.exe "D:\05NovRepo\PE\bin\Debug\PE.dll" --testcasefilter:"FullyQualifiedName=PE.Feature.Preconditions.DeleteData:Preconditions_DeleteDataFeature" /TestAdapterPath:"D:\05NovRepo\packages\SpecRun.Runner.3.0.344\tools\net45\"
```

Please note that I've tried with the ClassName as well and again it's not working:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow>vstest.console.exe "D:\05NovRepo\PortfolioEngine\bin\Debug\PortfolioEngine.dll" --testcasefilter:"ClassName=PortfolioEngine.Feature.Preconditions.DeleteData.Preconditions_DeleteDataFeature" /TestAdapterPath:"D:\05NovRepo\packages\SpecRun.Runner.3.0.344\tools\net45\"
```

**I need to use the exact match only that's why using = operator. I don't want to use ~ contains operator.**

Comment: What is the error you are getting?. Do you have test cases in that class?

Comment: Getting the error as: "No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=PE.Feature.Preconditions.DeleteData.Preconditions_DeleteDataFeature` in D:\05NovRepo\PortfolioEngine\bin\Debug\PortfolioEngine.dll" Also If I remove the class name that is "Preconditions_DeleteDataFeature" then also getting the same error.